# Can we filter multiple labels simultaneously

Tags: graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a scenario where I have to check multiple vertices with different labels and match their properties under a parent vertex. And then return the parent vertex if everything matches fine.

I tried writing queries with 'and' clause and 'where' clause but none is working:

Here are my trials:

```
g.V().hasLabel('schedule').inE().outV().hasLabel('url').as('a').outE().inV().aggregate('x').hasLabel('schedule').has('name', '3').as('b').select('x').hasLabel('states').has('name', 'federal').as('c').select('a')

g.V().hasLabel('schedule').inE().outV().hasLabel('url').as('a').outE().where(inV().hasLabel('schedule').has('name', '3')).where(inV().hasLabel('states').has('name', 'federal')).select('a')

g.V().hasLabel('schedule').inE().outV().hasLabel('url').as('a').outE().and(inV().hasLabel('schedule').has('name', '3'),inV().hasLabel('states').has('name', 'federal')).select('a')

g.V().hasLabel('schedule').inE().outV().hasLabel('url').as('a').outE().inV().aggregate('x').hasLabel('schedule').has('name', '3').as('b').select('x').unfold().hasLabel('states').has('name', 'federal').as('c').select('a')
```

Please guide me through the right path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely simplify your approach. I don't think you need the step labels and `select()` for what you are doing which is good, because they add cost to your traversal.  I tried to re-write the first traversal you supplied and I"m hoping I have the logic right, but regardless, I'm thinking you will get the idea for what you need to do when you see the change:

```
g.V().hasLabel('schedule').in().hasLabel('url').
  where(and(out().hasLabel('schedule').has('name', '3'),
            out().hasLabel('states').has('name', 'federal')))
```

You already have the "parent" that you want to return on the first line, so just do a filter with `where()` and add your filtering logic there to traverse away from each of those "parents".